# How to use sed to replace patterns with dynamic content may contains single/double quotes?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to dynamically generate table of content for my markdown files, and trying to add it into the start of my markdown files.

But the dynamically generated TOC may contains some single quote or double quote, which leads the fail of sed execution.

Is there a way that I can add these dynamically generated TOC to the beginning of file using sed? How?

Below is my script and the error info:

```
# filename: add_toc.sh
TOC=$(./gh-md-toc $1)
sed -i "1s/^/"$TOC"/" $1


# Execution 
./add_toc.sh my_doc.md
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Can you show a sample value of `TOC` that fails for you?

Comment: Why not avoid the issue altogether by doing something like `{ ./gh-md-toc "$1" ; cat "$1"; } > tmpfile` and then `mv tmpfile "$1"`?

Comment: @steeldriver, that's what I did after ask this question, but I'm still curious about if sed can do what I want to do in this question.

Comment: You're likely better off using `ed` - where you could use the `!` form of `r` to read the output of the TOC generator command into the file as text, with no possibility of it being interpreted

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `ed` rather than `sed`, with the `!` form of its `r` command to read the output of the TOC generator command into the file as text, with no possibility of it being interpreted.

Ex. (untested - since I don't have the `./gh-md-toc` script):

```
ed -s "$1" <<EOF
0r !./gh-md-toc "$1"
wq
EOF
```